# Cordova/Android: Do not open Google Maps when physical mailing address is tapped

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

My Cordova app displays a list of physical mailing addresses. If you accidentally tap on an address (while scrolling), android launches Google Maps. How could I prevent that?

PS: Addresses are not linked to anything and I have

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
```

which has no effect.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since I got no answers, I am posting a solution that worked for me in hopes it might help someone in a similar situation.

I enclosed each address in a `<span>` and added `onclick` handler to override the default behavior:

```
<span onclick="javascript:void(0)">1700 BROADWAY</span>
```

This is just a workaround, the disregard of `<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">` is regrettable.